# Ordering by month & year numbers in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the blow query that I'm trying to use in a BI tool.

```
select
to_char(date_trunc('month', l.date_created)::date, 'Month YYYY') as "Month / Year",
  count(distinct l.lead_id) as "# New Leads"
  from leads l
  where l.date_created >= {{date_range_start}} and l.date_created <= {{date_range_end}}
  group by date_trunc('month', l.date_created)
```

The grouping is working correctly, but I can't figure out how to write the order by to get the results to come back in descending order of month and year (going by numbers, not "january vs april" alphabetical)

Comment: `order by date_trunc('month', l.date_created) DESC`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is what OP doesnt want. April will came before January

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: sbell9 wants "*in descending order of month and year*" that's precisely what `order by ... desc` will do

Comment: The suggested way will return August -> July -> September

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right I was thinking you include the `to_char` as op did.

Comment: @sbell9: no it will not (assuming that `date_created` is a `date` or `timestamp` column)

Comment: sbell I think you should show us some sample data and expected output. I just realize you already using the same command. But I try in sqlfiddle and works as expected

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I copy/pasted your order by into my query, the results came back in that exact order.

Comment: I'm trying a different way to get the results I'm needing. If it fails I'll add some example data to the question.

Answer (score 3):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3b1ba/5)**

```
select
  to_char(date_trunc('month', created)::date, 'Month YYYY') as "Month / Year",
  count(*) as "# New Leads"
from Table1  
group by date_trunc('month', created)
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', created) desc
```